# I want to use my phone as a GPS, but I don't want to turn on high accuracy to assist Google's wardriving. What am I to do?

Tags: gps, geolocation, gps-tracking

I like using my phone as a GPS.  It has all the sensors and storage and everything.  [Even if I can't find a good app yet.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18345/looking-for-on-road-offline-gps-nav-software-on-android)

However (*since I am concerned about leaking private data, I have turned the location setting to device only, which means it only uses the GPS radio*), Waze constantly nags about turning on "high accuracy" location; meaning it wants to scan wi-fi, bluetooth, and everything else.  Which means that the OS will be shipping that info to Google/Alphabet HQ.

How can I use my phone as a GPS without assisting [Google's wardriving efforts](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/04/22/google_android_privacy_concerns/)?  GPS by itself [is highly accurate](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/44202/100572), or at least it was until Google decided to harvest wi-fi locations via a distributed Android network.  Or am I misremembering something?

Are these nags just part of apps, or is there something I can do to mitigate incessent nagging?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Device only" location mode, found under Settings->Location->Mode. The key performance impact of this setting is in the time to first location fix. It can take minutes to find your location initially, but later updates will be quick.

I am not sure whether you also need to disable use of WiFi and Bluetooth for scanning purposes, but if you are concerned about privacy I would disable these:
Settings->Location->Scanning

Comment: I have that turned on already, that's why Waze is nagging me to enable GPS+cell.